# Rotation around arbitrary axis

Tags: geometry

I want to rotate a 3D object around some arbitrary axis by an angle theta. How can I decompose an arbitrary rotation into rotations around the x-y-z axes?

Comment: Perhaps see "Euler angles" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles

Comment: You're asking " how do i decompose an arbitrary rotation into rotations around the x-y-z axes?" right?

Comment: @rschwieb yes, that's correct

Comment: A quick naive approach I can come up with is to consider some "thing" you want to rotate, then consider the composition of the following actions: start by rotating the "thing" in such a way that your axis you want to rotate around aligns with a coordinate axis, then do the desired rotation as this is easy around a coordinate axis, then do the inverse rotation of the rotation you started with. If you do all this I think you could end up with your desired rotation (I'd recommend treating all three steps as rotation matrices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rotation matrix about an arbitrary axis $a$ and by an arbitrary angle $\theta$ is given by $R$.  The three rotation matrices about $x, y, z$ axes are given by

$R_x = \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && c_1 && - s_1 \\ 0 && s_1 && c_1 \end{bmatrix} $

where $c_1 = \cos(\theta_x) $, $ s_1 = \sin(\theta_x) $

$R_y = \begin{bmatrix} c_2 && 0 && s_2 \\ 0 && 1 && 0 \\-s_2 && 0 && c_2 \end{bmatrix}$

where $c_2 = \cos(\theta_y) , s_2 = \sin(\theta_y) $

$R_z = \begin{bmatrix} c_3 && -s_3 && 0 \\ s_3 && c_3 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

Where $c_3 = \cos(\theta_z) , s_3 = \sin(\theta_z) $

Performing three consective rotations about $x$ then $y$ then $z$ results in

$R = R_z R_y R_x =\begin{bmatrix} c_3 && -s_3 && 0 \\ s_3 && c_3 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} c_2 && 0 && s_2 \\ 0 && 1 && 0 \\-s_2 && 0 && c_2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && c_1 && - s_1 \\ 0 && s_1 && c_1 \end{bmatrix}$

Multiplying the right most matrices first

$ R = \begin{bmatrix} c_3 && -s_3 && 0 \\ s_3 && c_3 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} c_2 && s_1 s_2 && c_1 s_2 \\ 0 && c_1 && - s_1 \\-s_2 && s_1 c_2 && c_1 c_2 \end{bmatrix}$

This multiplies to

$R = \begin{bmatrix} c_2 c_3 && s_1 s_2 c_3 - c_1 s_3 && c_1 s_2 c_3 + s_1 s_3 \\
c_2 s_3  && s_1 s_2 s_3 + c_1 c_3 && c_1 s_2 s_3 - s_1 c_3 \\
-s_2 && s_1 c_2 && c_1 c_2 \end{bmatrix} $

Looking at the first column of $R$ and the last row of $R$, angles $\theta_x, \theta_y, \theta_z$ can be found

First,

$ \theta_y = \sin^{-1} (- R_{31} ) $

(or it could be equal to $ \pi - \sin^{-1} ( - R_{31} ) $ )

Then, from the last row of $R$

$\theta_x = \text{Atan2}( R_{33} / c_2 , R_{32} / c_2 ) $

And from the first column of $R$

$\theta_z = \text{Atan2} ( R_{11} / c_2 , R_{21} / c_2 ) $

To make sure we got the right $\theta_y$, compute the remaining $4$ entries of the right hand side and compare with the corresponding entries in $R$.

Comment: I don't understand something here. For example, if θ is 0, then θy will be 0 (or 3.14), θx will be 1.57 and θz will also be 1.57. So that would mean that if I want to rotate by 0 degrees  around an arbitrary axis a, I will have to rotate around axis x by 90 degrees, around axis y by 0 (or 180) degrees and by axis z by 90 degrees? That does not make sense to me. And it seems from these equations that those angles are not dependent on arbitrary axis direction

Comment: If $\theta = 0$ the $R$ is the identity matrix, so automatically, $\theta_x = \theta_y = \theta_z = 0 $