# I need an alternative 3d rotation/translation matrix for a pygame visualization.

Tags: matrices, 3d, rotations, quaternions, python

[Rotation around arbitrary axis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4449911/rotation-around-arbitrary-axis)

```
# Operation 1
c1,s1 = cos(     X),sin(     X)
c2,s2 = cos(sign*Y),sin(sign*Y)
c3,s3 = cos(sign*Z),sin(sign*Z)
s1s2,s1s3,s2s3,s1s2s3 = s1*s2,s1*s3,s2*s3,s1*s2*s3
c1c2,c1c3,c2c3 = c1*c2,c1*c3,c2*c3
m = [
    [c2c3 ,s1s2*c3-c1*s3,c1c3*s2+s1s3 ],
    [c2*s3,s1s2s3+c1c3  ,c1*s2s3-s1*c3],
    [-s2  ,s1*c2        ,c1c2         ]
]
# Operation 2
x1 = x0*m[0][0]+y0*m[0][1]+z0*m[0][2]
y1 = x0*m[1][0]+y0*m[1][1]+z0*m[1][2]
z1 = x0*m[2][0]+y0*m[2][1]+z0*m[2][2]
```

This works perfectly for standard rotations but object tumbling is non-intuitive.

Observers know up/down/left/right/front/back.  I want to rotate an object around observer axes then rotate the rotated object around observer axes.

I would prefer a 4x4 matrix to handle rotation, translation, and perspective in one operation.  The code above shows my definition of two operations since all code in each block must be executed from start to finish as a unit to be atomic, consistent, isolated, and durable.

For those curious about my use of sign... I use a bilateral display where rotations around X are the same for both but rotations around Y and Z produce symmetric opposed rotations.  This all works very well, except for the tumbling problem.

The math escapes me so far.  I will keep trying, but I would love a hint or link.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want all iterated rotations to always be around fixed scene axes, and not around rotated axes.  Spinning around X,Y, and Z should be possible regardless of current rotation.

Comment: are you asking about matrix multiplication?

Comment: I asked for a different matrix multiplication than the one I showed.  That code works for the method described in the link I provided.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: You have a point $P_1$ in space with a certain distance to a point with the coordinates $P_0 =(0,\,0,\,0)$. And you want to rotate a point $P_2$ around the point $P_1$, which was rotated with $P_2$ around an axis that goes out from $P_0$, around an axis that goes out from $P_1$ and you want to describe that rotation of $P_3$ with a rotation matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that what you are looking for is the integration (in the calculus sense) of a rotation matrix according to some angular velocity $w$.  The standard formula for this is:

$$ \frac{dR}{dt} = [w]_\times R$$

where
$$[w]_\times = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && -w_z && w_y \\ w_z && 0 && -w_x \\ -w_y && w_x && 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Then at each time step you would update your rotation matrix with

$$R  \leftarrow R + ([w]_\times R)dt$$

Of course with this the rotation matrix will naturally drift from being a true rotation matrix (i.e. columns are length 1 and are mutually orthogonal), so you will occasionally have to correct for this drift.  It is for this reason most prefer quaternions for this type of calculation, there is only one constraint.

Comment: Great insight for another of my needs.  What I am looking for is the sense of picking up a ball in my hand, rotating it around x, y, or z as I experience them, and putting the ball down, then picking it up again and rotating around my x, y, or z again... any number of times.  I appreciate that Cartesian coordinate orbits decay as opposed to polar coordinates.  The game "space war" from 1959-1960s used polar coordinates for exactly this reason.  So, to reiterate... I care about the user experience and care not for the object's self-relative axes.  Iterated rotations around the user's axes.

Comment: A sudden instinct... add negative angles, form an angle matrix, rotate the angle matrix positive, keep the angles for the next iteration.  WAIT!  I just looked at what you posted and I think I just came up with it because yours hinted me in the right direction.

Comment: The difference for me is that R is not updated.  w is updated then R is recalculated from original points.

Comment: One last comment.  The client code observes the step from pi to -pi and brings the value back in range.  Decay is of lower order than this correction.  Something would have to wiggle back and forth away from the step for a long time.  Besides, this is all for a Human interface where angles are changed by keystrokes.  Thank you for getting me thinking.